# Yup: Array of Object Conditional Validation

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hook-form, yup

I have a data structure like this:

```
{
  isReceivesSalary: true,
  boardMembers: [
    {
      name: 'David',
      country: 'USA',
      additionalProperty: {
        isReceivingSalary: true
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Dave',
      country: 'France',
      additionalProperty: {
        isReceivingSalary: false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When `isReceivesSalary` is checked then at least one of the `boardMembers`  should have
property `isReceivingSalary` should be checked.

Below is my validation schema which is not working.

```
const boardMembersValidation ={
  isReceivesSalary: yup.boolean().required(),
  boardMembers: yup.array(yup.object.shape({
    name: yup.string().required(),
    country: yup.string().required(),
    additionalProperty: yup.object().shape({
      isReceivingSalary: yup.boolean()
    })
  }))
};
```

Is it possible to validate at least one of the `boardMember` should be receiving salary when  `isReceivesSalary` is true?
Also add validation message.

Comment: You have a typo `isReceiveSalary` vs `isReceivesSalary`